# Get Count Of Rows Created Per Day with Date Range

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table with customers that get added (a few dozen a day). I want to return a table in SQL where it shows all new rows created per day for the last week.

I am going off of a 'datetime' column which includes the date and time in a YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s format.

If I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_per_day, datetime AS datetime
FROM customers
WHERE datetime > '2023-10-20'
GROUP BY datetime;
```

it will return a ton of rows since the time is different for each entry. I just want to group by day and not time. I am so stuck with this. Thanks!

Comment: SOLVED!!! Thank you so much! I tried everything I could think of. I feel like an idiot, but a grateful idiot! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get rid of the time component. One way is through [the `DATE()` function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-function/):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_per_day, 
       DATE(datetime) AS datetime
FROM customers
WHERE datetime > '2023-10-20'
GROUP BY DATE(datetime);
```